# Data types in SOAP 1.2

Tags: xml, soap, types

Recently, I was looking through some SOAP-about documentation and saw few SOAP calls\responses. Of course that must be my noobness, but I was surprised to see that none of the variables didn't have a data type specified in tag.

So, the question is : how do we know exactly what data we get from SOAP call if there are no data types specified in response XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, a SOAP XML messages is associated with a **XML Schema** (a `*.xsd` file) which defines the exact structure of the XML message and the datatypes (and value ranges) for the XML elements.

See:

- [A simple overview of W3C XML Schema](http://www.codalogic.com/lmx/xsd-overview.html)
- [Using W3C XML Schema](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/11/29/schemas/part1.html)

Comment: Ok, but when do we get that schema on our client-side?

Comment: @user1116534: typically, the WSDL file that describes a SOAP services contains references to the XSD file. Usually, when you create the client-side proxy (or whatever it's called), the tools you use will inspect the WSDL and any XSD that are referenced, and they'll build up the proper code to call the web service, based on those fiels